# flexdashboard with 4 chart stack

Tags: r, knitr, flexdashboard

Easy question: How do I create a [flexdashboard](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/) with 4 (or more) charts in chart stack in one column.

Documentation alludes that it should be possible.

I thought it would be as simple as:

````
---
title: "Dygraphs Linked Time Series"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    social: menu
    source_code: embed
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dygraphs)
library(quantmod)
library(flexdashboard)

getSymbols(c("MSFT", "HPQ", "INTC"), from = "2014-01-01", auto.assign=TRUE)
```

### Microsoft

```{r}
dygraph(MSFT[,2:4], group = "stocks") %>% 
  dySeries(c("MSFT.Low", "MSFT.Close", "MSFT.High"), label = "MSFT")
```

### HP

```{r}
dygraph(HPQ[,2:4], group = "stocks") %>% 
  dySeries(c("HPQ.Low", "HPQ.Close", "HPQ.High"), label = "HPQ")
```

### Intel

```{r}
dygraph(INTC[,2:4], group = "stocks") %>% 
  dySeries(c("INTC.Low", "INTC.Close", "INTC.High"), label = "INTC")
```
### Fourth Row

```{r}
dygraph(INTC[,2:4], group = "stocks") %>% 
  dySeries(c("INTC.Low", "INTC.Close", "INTC.High"), label = "INTC")
```
````

Comment: What result does this create? Do you get errors? How is the output (if any) different from what you want?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is insert a paragraph between 
instead of

````
```
### Fourth Row
````

use

````
```

### Fourth Row
````